# How to fix deprecated error utf8_encode()

Tags: php

In php 8.2.0 function utf8_encode() is deprecated

Replace with this function

iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $string);

In API libraries etc this will work

It corrects the utf8_encode() deprecated function error

Comment: Is it a question?

Comment: If you don't like `iconv()` for whatever the reason, [php.watch](https://php.watch/versions/8.2/utf8_encode-utf8_decode-deprecated) lists a number of alternatives. But, as said, it isn't clear if you're asking anything. Plus it's possible that you didn't need `utf8_encode()` in the first place; it's been deprecated because many people made incorrect assumptions on it based on its name.